# Reference to WordExtractor is ambiguous

Tags: java, apache, file

I'm Trying to read from .doc file. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

public class ReadDocFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = null;
    WordExtractor extract = null;
    try {

        file = new File("c:\\New.doc");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fis);
        extract = new WordExtractor(document);
        String[] fileData = extract.getParagraphText();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
            if (fileData[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(fileData[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exep) {
    }
}
}
```

it is giving red error at following line:

```
extract = new WordExtractor(document);
```

The error is saying, 
Reference to word extractor is ambiguous
both constructor WordExtractor(DirectoryNode) in WordExtractor and Constructor WordExtractor(HWPFDocument) in WordExtractor match

Help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I added version 3.0 from

http://www.findjar.com/jar/poi/poi/3.0-FINAL/poi-3.0-FINAL.jar.html